# Using API Users.messages: delete

Tags: api, google-apps-script, gmail

I'm the admin of a school domain in google suites.  Someone hacked a student account and sent an unwanted message to all the students.  I have been tasked with deleting this message from all students accounts ASAP.  Google support directed me to the API Users.messages: delete.  When I attempt to use this API I get the error:

```
"domain": "global",
"reason": "invalidArgument",
"message": "Invalid id value"
"code": 400,
"message": "Invalid id value"
```

I'm grabbing the message id from the original email after choosing the "show original message" option. Please advise. Is this even possible to do?

Comment: Could you show full script? And there message screenshot after hiding sensitive information? Is the email in your account?

Comment: As @TheMaster has stated please, add more information of how are your doing your request. It seems that you should be using [Domain Wide Delegation](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation) and impersonate the users to delete all the messages.

Comment: Thank you for your responses!  The script can be found here:

Comment: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/delete

Comment: The offending email is not in my account, it's in a students account.  However I do have access to the student account it was sent with.  As I attempt to run the script I am logged into the student account.

Comment: Use this [api](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list) and see if the resulting messages and id are correct and equal to what you see manually in the inbox

Comment: the email doesn't exist in the students account anymore.  However it is in everyone account other then her.

Comment: Have you tried to list the mails from other users? Can't you just retrieve the email from every user and delete it then?